# Swap with atom as last parameter for the used function

Tags: clojure, atomic, swap

I have the following function:

```
(defn add-recommendations-to-cache [{:keys [trackingId rec-service recs]} cache]
  (assoc-in cache [trackingId rec-service] recs))
```

And I have my atom defined as:

```
(def cache (atom {}))
```

If I could change the order of the arguments passed to the function, I would  use:

```
(swap! cache add-recommendations-to-cache msg)
```

Since I can't, how can I `swap` using the atom, the function and a message that contains what the first argument requires? I have tried several possible combinations (see below), but none seem to work.

I've tried:

```
(swap! cache add-recommendations-to-cache msg cache)
```

and

```
(swap! cache (add-recommendations-to-cache msg))
```

and several others to no use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass your own function that applies the arguments in the order you want:

```
(swap! cache 
       (fn [current msg] (add-recommendations-to-cache msg current))
       msg)
```

or

```
(swap! cache #(add-recommendations-to-cache %2 %1) msg)
```

or close over `msg`:

```
(swap! cache #(add-recommendataions-to-cache msg %))
```

Comment: I think the one that closes over msg is better overall.